# How to decode encoded labels in Decision tree classifier

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, decision-trees

I have some dataset with procurements of organization where actually i'm working. The aim is to find most important features that describe why some processes of purchases is succesful, and why not succesful.

To solve this, I'm using Decision Tree Classifier.

First, I convert boolen columns to int

```
for col in ['flag_prequalification', 'flag_procurement_category_strategy']:
data.loc[:, col] = data.loc[:, col].astype(int)
```

Then, convert object type to string. This for label encoding

```
for cat_feature in categorical_features:
    data.loc[:, cat_feature] = data.loc[:, cat_feature].fillna('unknown').astype(str)
%%time
encoder = defaultdict(LabelEncoder)
data.loc[:, categorical_features] = (
    data
    .loc[:, categorical_features]
    .apply(lambda x: encoder[x.name].fit_transform(x), axis=0)
)
```

After, let's use log(sum) instead of sum

```
for col in ['sum_tru_no_nds (lot)', 'price (lot)', 'count (lot)']:
data[col] = (data[col] + 1).apply(np.log)
```

And, in the end plot the tree:

```
from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO  
from IPython.display import Image  
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
import pydotplus

import graphviz
# DOT data
dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=None, 
                                feature_names=None,  
                                class_names=target_col,
                                filled=True)

# Draw graph
graph = graphviz.Source(dot_data, format="png") 
graph
```

[image]

The question is, how can I explain this tree to others, more precisely how can I decode this labels in tree?

Answer (score 0):

First, setting `feature_names` will replace all the `X[2]` and such.  Using `feature_names=data.columns` is sensible, provided your feature names aren't too long for easy display.

Now, you'll still be comparing against the label encodings.  By saving the label encoder objects (your `encoder` dict), you can retrieve which levels correspond to the integer labels (with the `classes_` attribute, or possibly the `inverse_transform` method).  If your features have many levels, then you probably don't want to display all the levels in each split, and just providing them off to the side somewhere might be best.  If your features have few levels, maybe hacking the resulting DOT code will work; see [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63866683/10495893) of mine, which concerns one-hot encoded variables.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using scikit-learn to fit the decision tree, you should scikit-learn to encode the features. For example, scikit-learn's [OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) has the `get_feature_names` attribute which return feature names for output features.